# comparing dictionary values with same keys

Tags: python

Is there a clean, pythonic way to do the following?

1. compare all values from one dictionary to another without iterating over keys and comparing values?

I'm thinking either a list comprehension or a use of all() would play into this

right now I'm thinking that

```
for key in dict:
   if dict[key] > otherDict[key]
       return False
return True
```

any ideas?

Comment: "compare all values" - and what's the rule?

Comment: `dict_1 == dict_2`

Comment: wait why was this downvoted? was the question unclear?

Comment: @AnthonyChung: Yes. What kind of comparison? AvinashRaj's comment shows how to do equality comparison. You used greater than, but why? Also, what does "compare all values" mean, does it matter if the dictionaries values are equal, but connected to different keys?

Comment: It's like saying "compare two apples"! But how?

Comment: Fair point. I'll be more specific. "I am comparing the integer values located at each respective key" so the values at dict[key1]  against otherDict[key1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for key in dict:
   if dict[key] > otherDict[key]:
       return False
return True
```

is the same as

```
return not any(dict[key] > otherDict[key] for key in dict)
```

`any()` stops as soon as a true value is found which `not` then complements.

In a function context

Answer (score 0):

Given two dictionaries `dict1` and `dict2`, you could use `all()` combined with a generator:

```
all(v <= dict2.get(k) for k, v in dict1.iteritems())
```